# Quadratic function that produces natural number from natural number inputs

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, quadratics

I am currently trying to find a way to generate different (preferably quadratic) function as part of a *encryption algorithm* such that :

```
f(x) = natural number (where x is also a natural number)
```

So far, the only functions that I could think of would be straight line functions, which isn't the best thing to use in encryption.

Would there be a method to generate such a function (or does such a quadratic function even exist)? If no, are there any other kind of functions that could produce the sought after results?

I don't have the best background in mathematics (a student of computer science) so a thorough explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any polynomial with integer coefficients will generate integer outputs for integer inputs.

I assume that you have specific function values which you need to satisfy (i.e., $f(x)$ and $x$ are not necessarily arbitrary integers.)

If you have simple enough function values such that a quadratic function fits the data points, just take the quadratic form $y=Ax^2 + Bx+C$ and vary its parameters.

However, if you have a more complex set of data points to match a polynomial to, you interpolate a polynomial from the data points.

You say you don't have the best background in mathematics, so something like the [Lagrange interpolating polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html) might seem a bit off-putting, but it is quite intuitive once you spend some time thinking about it.

In the meantime, you can use [WolframAlpha's own interpolating polynomial calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolatingpolynomial&a=*C.interpolatingpolynomial-_*WolframLanguageSymbol-&f2=%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B4%2C4%7D%2C%7B9%2C9%7D%2C%7B16%2C16%7D%7D&f=InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data2%5Cu005f%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B4%2C4%7D%2C%7B9%2C9%7D%2C%7B16%2C16%7D%7D&a=*FVarOpt.1-_***InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data2--.***InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data---.*--) to generate functions that match your data points.

My final note is on [Cantor pairing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function). This quadratic function maps two natural numbers to one; it encodes two natural numbers in a second.

Furthermore you can prove that any function value of a Cantor pairing function has two unique associated numbers, it is a one-to-one correspondence.

This might be of interest to you. As long at the order $N$ of the key set and the set which you are encoding is the same, there should be $N/2$ pairing function values which encode the "key" data set.

Comment: Thank you! The `Cantor pairing function` did almost exactly what I was looking for, but I will go spend some time trying to understand `interpolating polynomials`